# Input transformer in SMPS

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, maximum-ratings

I'm trying to design an AC/DC power supply with around 15V/25A output. Looking at the reference design from TI (https://www.ti.com/reference-designs/index.html) I was wondering why their design don't just use an input transformer to step down the voltage at the input rather that something like  a boost PFC which increases the voltage hence increase the rating required for the components.

The input step down transformer would lower the voltage and also provide insulation so that topologies like flyback don't have to be used isolate instead, you could use a non-isolated topology like a buck to step voltage down even further, but this is not a design choice. Why is that?

Comment: What's your input specs?

Comment: Your link just takes us to the TI reference design index.  Please provide the link to the specific ref design you're asking about.

Comment: Please provide a more specific hyperlink to the design you are referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that simple.

Regardless of the type, a regulator in general is a capacitive (reactive) load. When connected directly across the mains, depending on the design, there are going to be reactive currents which basically bring extra burden on the transmission lines: The apparent power will increase while the real (usable) power remains the same. The rest (reactive power) is simply unusable, or garbage, but it's on the supply line.

The PFC is there to fix this. It tries to make the real power as close to the apparent power as possible (hence the name, PFC - power factor corrector).

For a 15V/25A switching regulator, we can expect an input power of 415W (or higher). Without any PFC pre-regulator the expected PF (power factor) would be around 0.6 which means an apparent power of 690VA. For 230V input, the input current would be 3A - 50+% more for no reason.

One other advantage of a PFC pre-regulator is that it outputs a constant DC voltage for the rest of the circuit. The rectified AC mains voltage can vary between 120 to 375V but the PFC pre-regulator outputs constant ~400VDC. So the design for the DC-DC converter becomes easier. From design and component selection point of view, 375V (rectified 264V mains) and 400V has no major difference. For example, even the cheapest MOSFET to be used in a flyback regulator will have a breakdown voltage of 650V (at least). So, to some extent, it doesn't matter if the input voltage is 325V (rectified 230V). 375V (rectified 264V) or 400V (PFC output).

The major disadvantage is, of course, cost and space due to its complexity. Although passive PFCs work well for low power levels and can be acceptable, they are terrible when it comes to keeping THD low.

Answer (score 1):

> *I'm trying to design an AC/DC power supply with around 15V/25A output*

That's a power requirement of 375 watts out <-- take note because any formal design produced by an IC supplier (such as reference designs by TI) must use PFC if above around 75 watts out.

If using PFC then a conversion to DC **must** take place.

When a conversion to DC takes place, a conventional 50/60 Hz transformer solution is out of the window. Even if you brought it back through the door, it wouldn't meet modern power factor performance by a mile.

> *I was wondering why their design don't just use an input transformer
> to step down the voltage at the input*

Hopefully you have that answer. Apart from anything else, the size of a transformer at 60 Hz is many times the volume of the same power-out transformer using a 100 kHz switching frequency.